# How do I validate int input using std::stoi() in C++?

Tags: c++, string, validation, int

Is there a way to check if string input is convertible to int using `std::stoi()` in C++? (For example, could I check to see if an invalid_argument exception will be thrown?)

*An example that doesn't work, but hopefully explains what I'm trying to do:*

```
    string response;
    cout << prompt;

    if (std::stoi(response) throws invalid_argument) { //Something like this
        return std::stoi(response);
    }
    else {
        badInput = true;
        cout << "Invalid input. Please try again!\n";
    }
```

**Research:**
I've found several ways to check if a string is an int, but I'm hoping there is a way to do it using `std::stoi()` which I haven't been able to find yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strtol

Comment: What is the type of `response`? Can you provide a complete example so that we can check for ourselves? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Updated to clarify

Comment: I've read the documentation.

Comment: "how can I check to see if an invalid_argument exception will be thrown?" why don't you just _catch_ the exception when it _is_ thrown, rather than trying to predict and avoid it? You can't use `stoi` to check whether `stoi` will throw an exception, without it throwing an exception ... of course.

Comment: @davmac That looks like it will work, why didn't you just submit it as an answer?

Comment: @davmac, ah I just saw your answer, nevermind.

Comment: @StarSweeper aye, just submitted. The reason I didn't post it initially as an answer is because it is _not_ an answer to the question you actually asked - which was how to "check to see if an invalid_argument exception will be thrown". This is a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you should try to avoid asking such questions. Concentrate on what it is you actually need.

Comment: @davmac it is an answer to my first question though, which was how can I check if the string was covertable to an int using std::stoi(), the second question (how so see if invalid_argument exception will be thrown) was added later for clarification. I can delete that part if it makes the question/answer more clear for others though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should catch the exception when it is thrown, rather than trying to predetermine whether or not it will be thrown.

```
string response; 
cin >> response;

try {
    return std::stoi(response);
}
catch (...) {
    badInput = true;
    cout << "Invalid input. Please try again!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::stoi()` throws an exception if conversion could not be performed.
Look at the "Exceptions" section in this c++ documentation
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

Answer (score -1):

std::stoi converts as much as possible, and only throws an exception if there is nothing to convert.  However, std::stoi accepts a pointer parameter representing the start index, which is updated to the character that terminated conversion.  [See MSDN stoi docs here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404860.aspx)

You can use stoi to test by passing 0 as the starting index, then verifying that the returned index is the same as the total length of the string.

Treat the following as pseudo-code, it should give you an idea of how to make it work, assuming response is a std::string:

```
std::size_t index = 0;
auto result = std::stoi(response, &index);
if(index == response.length()){
    // successful conversion
    return result;
}
else{
    // something in the string stopped the conversion, at index
}
```

Comment: "You can use stoi to test by passing 0 as the starting index" - you don't pass anything as the "starting index". The index of the first unconverted character (or the end of the string) is _stored_ in the pointer you provide. What that pointer points at beforehand is not examined by the function.